# Angular bootstrap modal

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using ui-bootstrap-tpl version 2.4.0 with Angular Dialog Service, and I have a problem with modal.

Problem occurs when I close modal:

- If I click OK, it closed and no error.
- If I click Cancel, it closed but have an error in console window:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: cancel

- If I click outside modal, it closed but have an error:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: backdrop click

Anyway to fix it? Thanks alot!

Comment: This is my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Pzm9I09tQlvPinHKFx9S?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to handle the `dismiss` case of the modal.

Here's an updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/M5OnOcJJG65pinWe2iKt

Essentially, you need to do something like this:

```
dialog.result.then(
    function () {
        // success case
        console.log('ok');
    },
    function () {
        // dismiss case
        console.log('cancel');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Very helpful!